# #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Question:0x00000103644cc8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When displaying all questions from the Questions table with `<%= @questions %>` I am getting the following in the view `#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Question:0x00000103644cc8>`.

In the controller I have:

`@questions = Question.all`

What am I doing wrong to display the Questions from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the questions and output in whatever HTML structure you want.

For example, as an unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li><%= question.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

To list the questions on index page the code should be something like as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= question.title %></td>
      <td><%= question.description %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@questions` is a collection, you either need to iterate through the collection in your view or pass it to a partial named `_question.html.erb`. to iterate you can do this:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <p>question.title</p>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise if you create a partial named `_question.html.erb` like this:

```
<p><%= question.title %><p>
```

in your main view you can then pass the `@questions` object to the partial like this and it will print all the members of the `@questions` collection

```
<% render @questions %>
```